Assertion Error: 4 columns passed, passed data had 3 columns. Python/ipynb
I am trying to convert a pro-football-reference stats table into a csv file that shows defensive stats vs rushing. In my program I was able to get 10 columns of data for my runningback stats, however when I implement the same code to defense stats i get hit with the error "Assertion Error: 4 columns passed, passed data had 3 columns"
Here is my code:
headers = [th.getText() for th in soup.findAll('tr')[1].findAll('th')]
headers = headers[1:]
print(headers[:5])

rows = soup.findAll('tr', class_ = lambda table_rows: table_rows != "thead")
player_stats = [[td.getText() for td in rows [i].findAll('td')]
                for i in range(len(rows))]
player_stats = player_stats[2:]

stats = pd.DataFrame(player_stats, columns = headers)
stats.head()

From the research I have done I think its due to the table having multiple "rush" headers over the stat headers I want, it also seems to have problems grabbing the teams names. Here is the table I am trying to grab from minus the remaining 30 teams. Or visit this link for the table: http://pfref.com/pi/share/kZhgC
Rush    Rush    Rush
Tm                   Att     Yds     TD
Arizona Cardinals   25.8    119.2   0.82
Seattle Seahawks    24.0    106.8   1.12


The code you've given here worked for me and scrapped the table in the link without any errors. I've used requests for downloading the content and "html.parser" to init the bs4 scrapper.

@WojciechArtichowicz okay that seems to work better and now I am getting the data, however, it is not showing the team names in the csv file just a number list. Any idea about that?
